# Subdomains vs. URL Path in shareable links

Tags: seo, subdomain, link-building, sharing

I am building a web application for questions and answers. Each question/answer page has all the required metadata for Facebook and Twitter, and we encourage users to share these pages.

I have a dilemma regarding the shared link structure:

### Option 1 - subdomains

Use a `questions.example.com` and `answers.example.com`, followed by an ID and optional text. The text is ignored by the request, which only takes the id into account.

```
http://questions.example.com/<question_id>/<question_text>
http://questions.example.com/12345/how-long-is-the-queue    # Example
http://q.example.com/12345                                  # Example
```

### Option 2 - URL path

This is the format used by stackoverflow.com and trello.com:

```
http://example.com/questions/<question_id>/<question_text>
http://example.com/questions12345/how-long-is-the-queue    # Example
http://example.com/q/12345                                 # Example
```

Server-wise, I can easily do both - I have a wildcard SSL certificate and Apache/NGinx configuration is pretty straightforward.

**Which option - subdomains or URL path - is preferred for shareble links?**

Comment: Or `http://example.com/how-long-is-the-queue` as ideally each question would have unique text for the name wouldn't it?

Comment: No necessarily. "yes" or "no" are pretty common answers, and "what's up" a common question - hence the unique id.

Comment: Oh I didn't get from the question that people were dynamically asking questions.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough - updated.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine, but the URL path has a slight benefit over subdomains, because the backlink juice would be concentrated on one domain. Managing one domain is also easier than multiple subdomains.

In all cases, I would put the id of the question/answer in the url, because it will make the url unique for sure.